# Use classes from a library's library?

Tags: java, android, class, libraries, conceptual

Let's say I have a `LibImplementationA` that includes a `LibInterfaces`.
`LibImplementationA` contains the implementations of `LibInterfaces`'s java interfaces .
My application uses the interfaces from `LibInterfaces` and the implementations from `LibImplementationA`.
I included `LibImplementationA` in my app, and I thought I could use the interfaces from `LibInterfaces` in my app's code. But I couldn't !
**Why ?**

To make my app work, I must include `LibImplementationA` **and** `LibInterfaces`.
So `LibInterfaces` is duplicated (in `LibImplementationA` and my app), and this seems really bad (in case of the update of `LibInterfaces`)

Last but not least, in my app I want to be able to switch from using `LibImplementationA` to `LibImplementationB` or `LibImplementationX` (that's why the app uses `LibInterfaces`).

My real problem is way more complex, but I need a clever idea to avoid duplications of this `LibInterfaces`, if possible!
I'm using Android Studio, with gradle.
Edit: for a better understanding, `LibInterfaces` contains communication interfaces (as simple as `sendMessage()`, `messageReceived()` methods) and `LibImplementationX` implements those methods using SIP, XMPP, WebSocket, Whatever.

Comment: Sorry, i am not clear, are you able to implement LibInterfaces in your class?

Comment: `LibImplementationX`'s classes successfully implements `LibInterfaces` 's interfaces, dunno if I answered your question

Comment: Lets say, your class is MyClass. and you can not do class MyClass implements LibInterfaces{ //... }
am I correct about your problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "duplicated"?  Just the `import ...LibImplementationX` statement at the top of the class?

Comment: In duplicated, I mean that in my android project LibImplementationX in libs/ I have LibInterfaces.aar; and in my android project application in libs/ I also have the same LibInterfaces.aar (and LibImplementationX.aar) ...

Answer (score 0):

The answer of "Why" - `LibInterfaces` could be protected/default scope interface & couldn't be implemented outside of that specific package.

Comment: All interfaces and classes are `public` :/

Comment: still you can't implement the interface in your class, is my understanding correct?

Comment: No, sorry I guess I didn't explained it right. To sum up my question is "In an App, how to use a class that is contained in a library's library, without duplicating the last library"... Looks like it doesn't clarify anything x)

Comment: may be I am confused. So I am trying to help you in general approach. there is nothing like library's library. if your parent library is in your project path then all the things it has got are part of your projects. So now you can import any public interface and implement them in your class as you wish. There shouldn't be any problem at all.